# Issue in validating the date using moment.js by format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Can some body explain me the behavior of the below moment.js code?

In the below code, date is validated fine and returns false as expected.

```
moment("32/02/2015", 'DD MM YYYY')
```

But if I change the format as below then the validation passes and return true.

```
moment("32/02/2015", 'DD MMM YYYY')
moment("31/02/2015", 'DD MMM YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

No it does not with the current realese of moment. Check your release.

Try it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y1t8xwf/)

```
alert(moment("32/02/2015", 'DD MMM YYYY'))
```

Nevertheless, the standard parsing is 'lenient', so it can try to accept an invalid date. For instance (see comment) 31/02/2015 is parsed as january 31 of year 2. You can force a strict parsing with a third parameter set to `true`.

```
moment("31/02/2015", "DD MMM YYYY") // returns Thu Jan 31 0002 00:00:00 GMT+0100
moment("31/02/2015", "DD MMM YYYY", true) // returns "Invalid date"
```

Comment: Yes now I agree with it. yet now it fails with 31/02/1025 which does not exist but it parse and produce a date.